# What does the "Update" button do for complex types in EF when using function import

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-designer

In EF, when you add a function import, you are asked to specify the name and the SProc. Then you can decide the return (it can be None, Scalers, **Complex**, and Entities).

What happens when you choose Complex and then press the update button? I think I screwed up my db  when I pressed the `Update` button. I reverted and then didn't press it and it works well.

So, what does Update do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update button doesn't affect DB. It is used if you modify your stored procedure and import it again and you want to update existing complex type instead of deleting it and creating a new one.

Comment: Ah I see. So what happened to me was that the complex type was auto-updated and broke the other SProc that was using it